# Implementing private_key_jwt and client_secret_jwt with Identity Server 4; providing client credentials using a JWT token

Tags: client, jwt, identityserver4

Using Identity Server 4, how do you hook into the exchange between the client and server when using the authorization_code flow to provide Client credentials to the Identity Server using a JWT Token?

Below is the solution:
In ConfigureServices the is key to hook into the Identity Server pipeline and  provide a call-back for the event OnAuthorizationCodeReceived. This event is called at the point in the pipeline where the authorization code is received back from Identity server during the normal exchange between the client and server as described by https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6750.txt.
 Doing this give you the opportunity to create the JWT token and make it available from that point on in the pipeline.

```
Configuration on the client
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    ... 

    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.Authority = "http://localhost:44320/";
        options.ClientId = "cliend-id";
        options.ClientSecret = "client-secret";

        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = delegate (AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
        {
            var clientassertion = new ClientAssertion("client-id", "http://localhost:44320/connect/token");
            var assertion = clientassertion.CreateJwtClientAssertionAsymmetric("localhost");

            context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientAssertion = assertion.ClientAssertion;
            context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientAssertionType = assertion.ClientAssertionType;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        ...
```

Configuration on the server
As http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/secrets.html?highlight=beyond indicates under the section beyond shared secrets.
The important bit here is to ensure the type and value are aligned as in the example below.

```
var client = new Client
{
    ...
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret
        {
            Type = IdentityServerConstants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateBase64,
            Value = "MIIDATCC..."
        }
    },
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
AllowedScopes = { "api1", "api2" }
```

};

Implementation

Implement the interfaces  ISecretParser and ISecretValidator
Then add to implementations to the DI system in ConfigureServices.

Eg.
builder.AddSecretParser()
builder.AddSecretValidator()

If your Validator is not getting called, ensure RequireClientSecret is set to true.
Take the appropriate action in the parser, and validator (from the parse return success for failure).

This approach work for both private_key_jwt and client_secret_jwt.

Comment: you are referring to this spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7521, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. With the client credential flow, it's clear how this should be done but not clear with using an MVC client and Identity Server 4.  The token and assertion are build, it's understanding where it needs to be added into Identity Server middleware.

Comment: So here is an older article that may help point you in the right direction.https://leastprivilege.com/2013/12/23/advanced-oauth2-assertion-flow-how/

Comment: Wow, that was a super response time, much appreciated. The link is useful and does shed some light on the issue. I understand what it says, and if I was using the client credential flow this would solve my issue. My understanding is that for MVC clients there is no obvious equivient to: client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1", assertion).  services.AddIdentityServer()
 .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication();

new Secret
{
    Type = IdentityServerConstants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateBase64,
    Value = "MIIC7DCCAdSgAwIBAgIQGNzNKrW/e6..."
}
MVC client client middleware use assertion?

Comment: I believe you MVC client is probably a Hybrid Flow which can use client credential flow too.

Comment: The client is using Authentication Code flow and there doesn't appear to be a clear point to insert the Assertion contiainng the token as the entire flow is controlled by Identity Server 4 middleware. This flow returns access and identity tokens. In this instance, sending a second request to get the access token does seem correct.

Comment: Can you share the client code that it uses to connect to the IdentityServer4?

Comment: Getting post error, too many characters.. but code is basically what's in the sample with response_type = code. There is no specific code as such to connect. As I undertand the middleware does the heavy lifting.

Comment: If you can't show the code it is hard for us to help you out.

Comment: `http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/secrets.html?highlight=beyond 
var client = new Client
{
    ...
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret
        {
            Type = IdentityServerConstants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateBase64,
            Value = "MIIDATCC..."
        }
    },

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    AllowedScopes = { "api1", "api2" }
};`  Attempting to write mvc client with authorisation code flow to use the scheme.

Comment: The code needs to go in the question and not the comments

Comment: Code is now in comment, let me know what you think. At this point it must be something simple I'm missing. :(

Comment: Ok, found the soultion. Please see the updated question which now contain the answer.